# Finding a single expression for a signal using unit-step functions

Tags: functions, signal-processing

So suppose that we have the signal x(t) shown in the figure below. How would I use unit-step functions to find just a single expression
for x(t) that is valid for all t.

[Unit Step Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1rwC.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_a(t)$ is the unit step function which is $0$ for $t<a$ and $1$ for $t\geq a$.  Then the function $u_a - u_b$ is $0$ for $t$ outside the interval $[a,b)$ and $1$ inside the interval. This little construction is the key to such things.  If you want to turn $f(t)$ on over the interval $[a,b)$ then write $f(t)(u_a -u_b)$. You get $f(t)$ in the interval and $0$ outside.  So for the function in your picture, you want $t+2$ between $-2\leq t <0$, and you write $(t+2)(u_{-2}-u_0).$  You want $2-t$ for $0 \leq t < 1$, so write $(2-t)(u_0-u_1)$. You want $1$ for $1\leq t <2$, so write $1(u_1-u_2)$.  Put them all together and the function you want is

$$(t+2)(u_{-2}-u_0)+(2-t)(u_0-u_1)+(u_1-u_2).$$

Comment: I'm not sure why \leq is not working, but \leqslant will display ok.

Comment: Also, I that should be (2-t) instead of 2-1.

Comment: @DisplayName, i think $\le$ is \le .

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson  Thanks!

Comment: hey @DisplayName, i tried editing the answer to include your correction, but the answer didn't change enough to be considered acceptable by the SE bot.  so it will remain $(2-1)$ instead of $(2-t)$ until someone else fixes it.

Comment: wow, the way you explained it is great. it's a lot easier than what i thought it would be. Although I don't think I've seen the function (Ua-Ub) before. I'm sorry my editing is off, i'm new to this site